# How to connect to a webpage with a proxy and keep the document in English

Tags: c#, proxy, httpwebrequest, webrequest, httpwebresponse

I am trying to connect to https://www.aliexpress.com/ with a proxy and I realized that if I connect with a proxy to that webpage, let's say I am using a Russian proxy, it's going to change the document to Russian, the currency will be Russian and the majority of the content on the page will be in Russian so what are my options here?
Are there any headers or cookies I can set to change the currency and the content?
I know there is a function on the webpage (top right) to change the currency etc to USD.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var proxyObject = new WebProxy("94.230.114.89:8585", true);

            var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(
                "https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Summer-Women-Shawl-Jacket-Woman-Thin-Section-net-yarn-in-long-paragraph-cardigan-Tops-wild-Sun/32893204463.html?spm=a2g01.11147086.layer-iabdzn.3.37286140RwQen9&gps-id=5275233&scm=1007.16233.92930.0&scm_id=1007.16233.92930.0&scm-url=1007.16233.92930.0&pvid=a9dbf8fb-6fd5-41e9-8b89-1d161da2fa58");
            request.Proxy = proxyObject;

            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US");
            var response = request.GetResponse();

            var data = response.GetResponseStream();
            var html = string.Empty;
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(data))
            {
                html = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            Debug.Print(html);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: It likely depends on how the website is determining the client's language. Which website is it?

Comment: "Content-Language" is a response header, "Accept-Language" is the request equivalent.

Comment: @DanWilson the website in the example

Comment: Try setting the thread culture to `en-US` from where your proxy requests are generated